# Помогите с Запросом MySQL

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица

```
id   name  c1   c2   c3 ...... cN
1     a     1    0    1 ...... 0         
2     b     0    0    1 ...... 0 
3     c     1    0    1 ...... 1
........
M     z     0    1    1 ...... 0
```

Заранее неизвестно, сколько столбцов cN может быть.
Можно ли каким либо образом составить запрос, чтобы выбирались только те записи, в которых с3 равно 1, а все остальные поля равны 0 ? К примеру из указанной таблицы должно выбрать запись с id=2.
Спасибо.

Comment: Мне кажется решение задачи кроется в правильности её постановки. Что вы хотите решить этим запросом? Ведь нельзя быть уверенным, что есть c3. Выборка слишком уж непредсказуема.

Comment: Так можно сделать. Но это будет слишком затратно и извращенно. Лучше сказать зачем вам такое надо, точнее какова задача, скорее всего у задачи будет другое решение.

Comment: c3 есть в любом случае, столбцов cN там изначально 10, но в теории может быть увеличено, до 15. 15 - это максимум. Зачем мне это надо? Ну допустим, это таблица, в которую записывается какой-то набор действий, совершенный сотрудником. И мне нужно выбрать только такие записи, где он сделал только что-то одно, в данном случае c3. Как-то так.

Comment: @mrx  Может все же озвучите что конкретно вы вообще пытаетесь сделать? И тогда может более что-то адекватное вам посоветуют. Потому, что **1)** Если выбирать `id=2`, тогда в любом случае выберется **только одна запись** ... если нужно **2)** несколько записей, то разве не хватает вам `SELECT something FROM table WHERE c3=1 ` ?

Comment: да я вроде выше озвучил, просто не сразу получилось полностью описать, пришлось редактировать...  Можно выбрать и все с с3=1, потом работать на выходе, вычленяя те записи, в которых что-то кроме с3 равно 1. Меня просто интересует, можно ли сразу выбрать то, что нужно, чтобы потом не париться с обработкой.

Comment: А, то есть если хотя бы одно поле из остальных не равно нулю, то не выбирать запись? Вы так хотите?

Comment: да, именно так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой возможности нет.
Рекомендую делать структуру таблиц максимально простой и с наименьшим количеством столбцов. Это ускоряет запросы и облегчает разработку.
Если Вы напишите причину подобной необходимости, возможно, удастся найти другой подход.

Comment: Да я стараюсь это сделать, в смысле упростить. До меня тут все эти c1...cN  записывались вообще в одну ячейку в виде JSON. Это уже я их разложил по отдельным ячейкам.

Comment: @mrx Может не спроста все же там был `json` то?

Comment: может....  но теперь, когда там >5000 записей, заказчик захотел увеличить состав этого JSON, предлагаете мне каждый раз при таких изменениях пробегать по всем записям и изменять в каждой ячейке эту JSON запись ? )))

Comment: Если в некоторых структурах JSON данных будут отсутствовать некоторые ключи, это не проблема. Все это должно правильно обрабатываться в PHP и строить верные данные для отправки в шаблон.

Comment: Предположим, что в новых записях в JSON были добавлены с5 и с6, соответственно, в старых записях их не будет. Тогда, в обработке этих данных в PHP, для старых записей ключи c5 и c6 по умолчанию считать равными 0.

Comment: В вашем случае напрашивается изменение архитектуры БД - создать 2 таблицы. В одной хранить id записи и минимум важных данных. Во второй хранить параметры записи. В этом случае любая запись может иметь любые параметры в любом количестве.

Comment: Недавно обсуждали подобное на [тостере](https://toster.ru/q/263088)

Comment: @psaproxy Вот только хотел написать об этом)) Сделать связанные таблицы гораздо проще и правильнее будет, чем таблицу с кучей полей, которых могут не быть

Comment: Все бы ничего, но в этом случае добавление новых записей - это как правило разбиение одного целого на две составляющие. То есть, к примеру, было одно действие, включающее два пункта (из которых один мог и не выполняться, но записи все равно присваивалась 1), а теперь каждый пункт стал отдельным действием. И поэтому далеко не всегда новые записи в JSON содержат в себе 0. Насчет изменения архитетктуры - это первое, о чем я подумал. Но надеялся, что найдется какое-то просто решение к существующей задаче

Comment: Сожалею, я не понял сути Вашего коментария. Выгода в том, что Вы сможете выполнять различный поиск по параметрам, а так же добавлять новые. Для обновления структуры будет достаточно написать класс-модель. Это займет не более 1-2 часов включая тесты. А далее самое легкое - изменить обработку запроса. Перенести записи из старой таблицы в новые - код на 5-10 строк.

Comment: Да суть проста. В нём я сожалею ,что не нашлось простого более менее стандартного решения для задачи при описанных условиях. Буду менять БД :) Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE c3 = 1 AND c1 = 0 AND c2 = 0.... AND cN = 0
```

По другому ни как.

Comment: Извините, а как вы поняли эту фразу из вопроса: _Заранее неизвестно, сколько столбцов cN может быть_?